# Can't move a circle on canvas html?

Tags: javascript, canvas

So this is my code. I have no idea why the circle isn't moving. It just stays where I stated its x and y coordinates as.

```
class Circle {
constructor(x, y, r, clr) {
this.radius = r;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.clr = clr;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle = this.clr;
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
}

move(finalx, finaly) {
  this.finalx = finalx;
  this.finaly = finaly;

  while (this.finalx != this.x && this.finaly != this.y) {
    this.x += 2;
    this.y += 2;
 }

}
}

var x = new Circle(150, 225, 50, black);
x.move(400, 25);
```

Comment: The HTML5 Canvas doesn't work like Flash. For animation on the Canvas you have to draw and clear the Canvas on every frame. Check any tutorial on the web for that. [For example](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/creating_simple_html5_canvas_animation.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You need to redraw your canvas after each update. You probably want something like this:

```
class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, r, clr) {
        this.radius = r;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.clr = clr;
        draw();
    }

    move(finalx, finaly) {
      this.finalx = finalx;
      this.finaly = finaly;

      while (this.finalx != this.x && this.finaly != this.y) {
        this.x += 2;
        this.y += 2;
        draw();
      }
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500); // Enter your specific dimensions
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.clr;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty good, but a delay between the calling of the draw method would be even better!